# How to start process as a daemon?

Tags: python, daemon

I have created a service which consists of a web fronted (nginx), python runner glue handler (uwsgi) and my own python code (fetcher). I have made a script (deploy.sh) to start the difference services:

```
nginx
uwsgi --ini inifie.ini
python fetcher.py & disown
```

My question is regarding how I start my python daemon. I want it to run in the background. It should not print anything to my current terminal. If I add "print" calls to my fetcher script I currently see them in the terminal window.

So my question is: how do I start my fetcher.py script as a daemon?

Comment: Quick solution use "screen". Start your screen with "screen -S fetcher" then start your script and send it to background. Or follow this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423345/can-i-run-a-python-script-as-a-service

Comment: If you're on Fedora you could use systemd to glue everything together.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [python-daemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) package or use [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html).

Please also see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to do this from the shell script or from the Python program?

If from the shell script, it's quite simple:

```
nohup fetcher.py >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null & disown
```

If you want to do it from the Python program, I suggest you look into using [the python-daemon module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon), also probably available as a pre-made package for your favorite Unix-like OS.

Answer (score 2):

I often do a fork like this in the python program:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid > 0:
            sys.exit(0)
    except OSError:
        report( "unable to fork: %s" % sys.exc_info()[1])
        raise
    [program starts here ]
```

Comment: It's not that simple.  You should at least do a double fork, and also setsid().  And what about stdout/stderr?  Simpler to just use the python-daemon module.

Comment: True, it's not quite that simple, but at least he's pointing the poster toward an actual daemon vs a hack with nohup or screen.  Handle cwd and standard file handles then you get even closer to an actual daemon.  Do you run apache in a screen session?

Answer (score 1):

Simple workaround is: `nohup`

```
nohup myprogram > myprogram.log &
```

Answer (score 0):

supervisord works well, and can be confied to send out alerts on failures